# JSF beans instantion: Are only the beans referenced in the view instantiated?

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, managed-bean

I'm guessing that if I have 6 requestscoped beans, only those referenced by the current view ( for instance by using #{foo.bar}) are instantiated. Is that assumption correct? In that case the only bean created would be foo, and not foo2, foo3, etc that are also requestscoped or viewscoped, etc.

Does this happen to both CDI's @Named and jSF's @ManagedBean beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

You can test that by logging a message / adding a breakpoint in the constructor of all beans.

Comment: True, but I'd recommend to use the @PostConstruct lifecycle hook over the constructor, because the spec requires the application server to call this method (there are no assumptions made on calling the constructor)

Comment: @jan groth agreed. For the sake of testing it wouldn't matter that much, but otherwise - always prefer postconstruct